# R: Attribute Overepresentation in a cluster

Tags: r, p-value, hierarchical-clustering

I performed hierarchical clustering in a dataset with 4 categorical variables (2 nominal, 2 ordinal) in R using `hclust` and `daisy` to compute the dissimilarity matrix. Using the following code I can summarise the attributes' distributions in each cluster (I change the cluster.membership number accordingly):

```
library(Rcmdr)
x <- cutree(aggl.clust.c, 5)
cluster.membership <- factor(assignCluster(my.data, my.data, x))
y <- my.data3[cluster.membership==1,]
summary(y)
```

However, I would like to find a way to indicate that an attribute is overepresented in a cluster, compared to the whole sample.

For example, in the picture, there are the counts of each attribute of each variable for cluster 1 (e.g. In cluster 1 var1=1 for 50 observations, var1=2 for 25 observations etc). Let's say that some attributes within the cluster have much larger counts compared to the whole sample. For example, I can see by looking at the summaries that var4=1 for 200 observations, a number much larger compared to var4=1 counts to other clusters. I would like to show that the result is signficant (χ2-test with significance α = 0.05), by comparing the counts of the specific attribute (here var4=1) and not by examing the whole distribution of the variable.

[image: Example of cluster summary]

Is there a function in R that could calculate that, by e.g. calculating the p-value for each attribute?

Comment: Could you clarify for us what it means to be "over-represented" in a cluster?  How are we supposed to interpret the entries in the cells of your picture?  What do the numbers and colons represent?  What would it mean for a *variable* to be "significant"?

Comment: @whuber I am sorry I will edit my question accordingly

Comment: @whuber I hope it is more clear now, please let me know if I need to elaborate more